# Query using .where not working when string contains more than one word

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add the ability to filter posts by keywords. I have it working if a post only includes one keyword, but it doesn't work when a post has multiple keywords. I think I understand why it doesn't work, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

This is the method in the controller:

```
KEYWORDS = ["authorlife", "lostlegacies", "ashiftinshadows", "snippets", "artwork", "random"]

def filter

    filtered_posts = Post.all
    
    KEYWORDS.each do |keyword|
      if params[keyword] == true
        filtered_posts = filtered_posts.where(keywords: keyword)
      end
    end
    
    render json: filtered_posts

  end
```

In the case where a post only has one keyword I think it works because my query is basically checking if the keywords for a post match the keyword in the loop. So if I only have keyword, let's say "keyword1" in the post and the keyword it's looking for is "keyword1" then it works. But if I have two keywords then it's trying to match "keyword1" but only finding posts that have "keyword1 keyword2" and because the second keyword is there it doesn't match. I'm not sure if I should be doing something with `includes?` or `ILIKE`. I've tried a couple different things and still can't figure this out.

Comment: Do you want to have your query find post with any of the keyword or ALL of the keywords?

Comment: I want it to find a post with any of the keywords. So if on the frontend I say, show me posts that have "keyword1", I want the query on the backend to return any post that has "keyword1" as a keyword. Even if it has other keywords as well. For example if it has "keyword1 keyword2" it should still be included.

Comment: you need to use full-text search mechanism to search for multiple tags saved in a single column. For postgres, you can use https://pganalyze.com/blog/full-text-search-ruby-rails-postgres. Alternatively, you can use elasticsearch(searchkick gem).

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem here is that you're most likely storing the keywords wrong. The only way using `LIKE` will actually fix the problem is if you're storing the keywords in a comma separated string or something simular. Storing multiple values in a column like that violates first normal form and you're really just introducing bugs in your application and hurting performance by using pattern matching. An example of these bugs is that `LIKE %foo%` will match `foo_bar` and `foo_bar_baz`, ooops.

A slightly better solution would be to use a native array or JSON/JSONB type column.

But the best solution would be to use a normalization table and join table to avoid duplicating the keywords.

First generate the model and join table

```
rails g model keyword text:string:unique
rails g migration create_posts_keywords_join_table posts keywords
```

Then setup the assocations:

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords
end
```

This will let you filter posts by keyword by doing a LEFT JOIN:

```
Post.joins(:keywords)
    .where(keywords: { text: keywords })
```

Comment: This was how I originally planned on doing this but I couldn't figure out how to switch keywords over to it's own table without breaking all the things. I think this is still the approach I want to take so I'll make a new post for that.

Comment: New post created here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946768/split-table-into-two-associated-tables

Answer (score 0):

I changed my query to this:

```
filtered_posts = filtered_posts.where("keywords like ?", "%#{keyword}%")
```

And it's working now. Not sure if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the Posts that have a keyword in the KEYWORDS array, ActiveRecord can handle the array for you:

```rb
Post.where(keyword: KEYWORDS)

#this generates the sql query:
# select posts.* from posts where posts.keyword in ('authorlife','lostlegacies', ...etc)
```

Comment: This won't actually work as the column is called `keywords` and most likely contains a string with a separator. If it was an actual array column you would need to use `@>` on PG.