# Split table into two associated tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an app that has a blog feature. Originally when I set this up a post post consisted of a title, body, keywords, and image link. I want to be able to filter posts based on keywords and I think the cleanest way to do this is to move keyword to their own table and associate the two tables. So each posts can have multiple keywords and each keyword can have multiple posts.

I created a migrations and model for keywords.

```
class CreateKeywords < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :keywords do |t|
      t.string :keyword

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

I associated that with the posts table and changed the posts model.

```
class CreatePostsKeywordsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :posts, :keywords do |t|
      t.index [:post_id, :keyword_id]
      t.index [:keyword_id, :post_id]
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords
  # validates :keywords, presence: true
  
end
```

For now I just commented out the keywords in the Post model. I'm not exactly sure if I need to remove it or not. I already have existing posts that I don't want to lose as part of this switchover so I'm trying to keep that I mind as I figure out how to make this work. Where I'm really confused is what I need to change in the controller.

This is my Post Controller:

```
require 'pry'

class Api::V1::PostController < ApiController
  before_action :authorize_user, except: [:index, :show]

  # INDEX /post
  def index
    render json: Post.all, each_serializer: PostSerializer
  end

  # SHOW /post/1
  def show
    render json: Post.find(params[:id]), serializer: PostShowSerializer
  end

  # CREATE /post/new
  def create
    binding.pry
    post = Post.new(post_params)
    post.user = current_user

    if post.save
      render json: post
    else
      render json: { errors: post.errors.full_messages }
    end 

  end

  # UPDATE /post/update
  def update
    post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if post.update(post_params)
      render json: post
    else
      render json: { errors: post.errors.full_messages }
    end
  end

  # DESTROY /post/destroy
  def destroy
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
  
    if post.destroy
      render json: {destroyed: true}
    end
    
  end
  
  protected

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit([:title, :body, :image, :keywords])
  end

  def authorize_user
    if !user_signed_in? || current_user.role != "admin"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

In the above state when I get to this part `post = Post.new(post_params)` I get an error saying `NoMethodError (undefined method 'each' for "authorlife":String)`. If I remove `keywords` from the `post_params` I get this error `Unpermitted parameter: :keywords`

I feel like I am missing one or more steps here but it's been awhile since I've done anything with associated tables like this.

UPDATE:
Followed some of the advice below and I updated the above code to how it currently looks. Current issue is that when I check `post_parms` in the `#create` method I'm no longer receiving keywords at all. I checked the frontend and it's sending keywords. I'm assuming it's my `post_params` that's causing the problem. I've tried adding the keywords nested attribute like this but keywords still isn't showing up in the `post_params`

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image, :keywords_attributes => [:id, :keyword])
  end
```

This is the WIP for the code I'm trying to implement. I'm not sure what the keywords part is supposed to look like once I get the params situation figured out.

```
params = { post: {title: post_params["title"], body: post_params["body"], image: post_params["image"], keywords_attributes: [{ keyword: 'keyword title' },]
}}
```

Comment: you should remove the keywords method from the Post model, it conflicts with the method of the same name that is introduced by the HABTM association. The unpermitted parameter error can occur when the parameter is permitted but it doesn't contain one of the default, accepted types. I think your front-end probably sends an array of strings for the keywords value (right?). If so you need to indicate that in the post_params methods with `keywords: []`.

Comment: should be `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image, keywords: [])`

Answer (score 1):

> In the above state when I get to this part post = Post.new(post_params) I get an error saying NoMethodError (undefined method 'each' for "authorlife":String). If I remove keywords from the post_params I get this error Unpermitted parameter: :keywords

You need to setup nested attributes for keywords if you want to update them through a post.

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords
end
```

You can then pass in params structured like this in your controller

```rb
params = { post: {
  title: 'title', body: "body", keywords_attributes: [
    { text: 'keyword title' },
  ]
}}

post = Post.create(params[:post])
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

> I already have existing posts that I don't want to lose as part of this switchover so I'm trying to keep that I mind as I figure out how to make this work.

It's good practice to remove this not used data anymore. You should write a data migration which moves the existing keywords from the posts table to the keywords table. Something like this

```rb
class KeywordsMigrator
  def run
    Post.all.each do |post|
      keyword = Keyword.find_or_create_by(title: post.keyword)
      post.keywords << keyword
    end
  end
end
```

Finally you can drop the `keyword` column from post.

You haven't really mentioned the current structure of the posts table so I assume you have a `keyword` column there. If you have a `keywords` column you have to name your association different until you remove the column otherwise you will run into troubles. For example you rename it to `keywords_v1` and specify the `class_name`.

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords_v1, class_name: "Keyword"

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true  
end
```

Or you rename the column first to something like `deprecated_keywords`.

Comment: I updated the Post model like you suggested. Renamed the `keywords` column in the Post table to `deprecated_keywords`. I couldn't get the migration for the keywords to work but I'm adding that to the (problems for later category). I made an update to my main code above with the problem I'm running into on the Controller side.

Comment: How does your params look?

Comment: When I check to see what I'm getting back for params this is what I have:

[1] pry(#<Api::V1::PostController>)> post_params
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"Test Post 4", "body"=>"Blah", "image"=>"https://maddox-grey-author.s3.amazonaws.com/magical-tree.jpg"} permitted: true>


This is how my `post_params` are set:

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image, keywords_attributes: [:id, :keyword])
  end

Comment: Do I need to change how I'm sending the data from the frontend? It currently looks like this in the POST request: `formData
{title: "Title 4", body: "Blah", image: "www.test.com", keywords: "authorlife"}`

Comment: It needs to be `keywords_attributes` like described in the example.

Comment: Changing `keywords` on the frontend to `keywords_attributes` helps in that I can now see it on the backend. But I can't figure out how to set the Strong Params to allow it. I keep getting `Unpermitted parameter: :keywords_attributes`